# Yii2 News not showing in Update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I am currently having problem with a news module i am trying to create in yii2.

I have multiple of fields that pertain to animal products or plant products. Items that doesn't pertain to animal will not be shown and vice versa.

Now it works well in create but in update it doesn't show up.

[image]

newsscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function cleardrop() {
        $('#newscommodity').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");                                   
        $('#newsgroups').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");                                     
        $('#newsorigin').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");                                          
        $('#newsmanufacture').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
        $('#newsintendeduse').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>"); 
        $('#newsfinality').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
        $('#newsspecies').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>"); 
    }
    var dept= $('#newsdepartment').val();
    if(dept=='Animal Health'){      
        $("#newsimportcategory").html(
            ["<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>",
            "<option value='Animal and Animal Products'>Animal and Animal Products</option>",
            "<option value='Animal Feed, Biologics and Veterianry Drugs'>Animal Feed, Biologics and Veterianry Drugs</option>"
        ]);

        $('#newsimportcategory').change(function () {
            var impcat= $(this).val();
            if(impcat=='Animal and Animal Products'){                    
                $('#newscategorylabel').removeClass("hide");                   
                $('#newscommoditylabel').removeClass("hide");                                                                        
                $('#newsspecieslabel').removeClass("hide");                                                        
                $('#newsoriginlabel').removeClass("hide");                                                                                   
                $('#newsfinalitylabel').removeClass("hide");                                              
                $('#newsmanufacturelabel').addClass("hide");                                           
                $('#newsgroupslabel').addClass("hide");                                  
                $('#newsintendeduselabel').addClass("hide");
                $.post("/import-conditions/admin/animal/listsimptcat",function(data) {
                    $( "select#newscategory").html(data)                                             
                });
                $('#newscategory').change(function () {
                    cleardrop();
                    $.post("/import-conditions/animal/listscommodity?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data) {
                        $("select#newscommodity").html(data)                                 
                    })                           
                }); 
                $('#newscommodity').change(function () {
                $.post("/import-conditions/animal/listsspecies?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data) {
                    $("select#newsspecies").html(data)                                     
                })      
                $.post("/import-conditions/animal/listsorigin?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data) {
                    $("select#newsorigin").html(data)                                     
                }) 
                $.post("/import-conditions/animal/listsfinality?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data) {
                    $("select#newsfinality").html(data)                                     
                });
            });
            $('#newsorigin').change(function () {
                $.post("/import-conditions/animal/listsfinalitysinglesearch?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data) {
                    $("select#newsfinality").html(data)                                   
                }) ;
            });
        } else if(impcat=='Animal Feed, Biologics and Veterianry Drugs'){                           
            $('#newscategorylabel').removeClass("hide");                                                   
            $('#newscommoditylabel').removeClass("hide");                                                                            
            $('#newsgroupslabel').removeClass("hide");                                                                         
            $('#newsoriginlabel').removeClass("hide");                                                                                       
            $('#newsmanufacturelabel').removeClass("hide");
            $('#newsintendeduselabel').addClass("hide");                                        
            $('#newsfinalitylabel').addClass("hide");
            $('#newsspecieslabel').addClass("hide"); 
            cleardrop();
            $.post("/import-conditions/admin/vetdrugsbiologicsfeed/listsimptcat",function(data) {
                $( "select#newscategory").html(data)                                           
            });
            $('#newscategory').change(function () {
                        cleardrop();
                    $.post("/import-conditions/vetdrugsbiologicsfeed/listscommodity?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                       {
                           $( "select#newscommodity").html(data)

                       }) ;
                });

                     $('#newscommodity').change(function () {
                    $.post("/import-conditions/vetdrugsbiologicsfeed/listsgroups?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                    {
                        $( "select#newsgroups").html(data)

                    })      


                $.post("/import-conditions/vetdrugsbiologicsfeed/listsorigin?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                    {
                        $( "select#newsorigin").html(data)

                    }) 

                     $.post("/import-conditions/vetdrugsbiologicsfeed/listsmanufacture?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                    {
                        $( "select#newsmanufacture").html(data)

                    }) ;
                 });

        }
        else if(impcat==''){

                                      $('#newscategorylabel').addClass("hide");                                  
                                       $('#newscommoditylabel').addClass("hide");                                    
                                         $('#newsgroupslabel').addClass("hide");                                        
                                           $('#newsoriginlabel').addClass("hide");                                           
                                             $('#newsmanufacturelabel').addClass("hide");
                                               $('#newsintendeduselabel').addClass("hide"); 
                                                $('#newsfinalitylabel').addClass("hide");
                                                 $('#newsspecieslabel').addClass("hide"); 
                                                    cleardrop();
        }   

     });

    }
    else if(dept=='Plant Health')
    { 
        $("#newsimportcategory").html(
        ["<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>",
        "<option value='Beneficial Organisms'>Beneficial Organisms</option>",
        "<option value='Plant and Plant Products'>Plant and Plant Products</option>"
        ]); 
         $('#newsimportcategory').change(function () {
         var impcat= $(this).val();

        if(impcat=='Beneficial Organisms'){

                                     $('#newscategorylabel').removeClass("hide");
                                      $('#newsspecieslabel').removeClass("hide");
                                       $('#newsoriginlabel').removeClass("hide");
                                        $('#newscommoditylabel').addClass("hide");                                  
                                         $('#newsfinalitylabel').addClass("hide");
                                          $('#newsmanufacturelabel').addClass("hide");
                                           $('#newsgroupslabel').addClass("hide");
                                            $('#newsintendeduselabel').addClass("hide");

                                        cleardrop();
                $.post("/import-conditions/admin/beneficialorganisms/listsimptcat",function(data)
                      {
                          $( "select#newscategory").html(data)


                      });

                $('#newscategory').change(function () {
                    cleardrop();
                    $.post("/import-conditions/beneficialorganisms/listsspecies?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                          {
                              $( "select#newsspecies").html(data)

                          })  
                          $.post("/import-conditions/beneficialorganisms/listsorigin?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                          {
                              $( "select#newsorigin").html(data)

                          }) 

                });



        }
        else if(impcat=='Plant and Plant Products'){

                                      $('#newscategorylabel').removeClass("hide");                                   
                                       $('#newscommoditylabel').removeClass("hide");
                                        $('#newsspecieslabel').removeClass("hide");
                                         $('#newsintendeduselabel').removeClass("hide");                                                                        
                                           $('#newsoriginlabel').removeClass("hide");                                            
                                             $('#newsmanufacturelabel').addClass("hide");
                                               $('#newsfinalitylabel').addClass("hide");
                                                 $('#newsgroupslabel').addClass("hide");

                                                cleardrop();

                 $.post("/import-conditions/admin/plants/listsimptcat",function(data)
                      {
                          $( "select#newscategory").html(data)


                      });

                      $('#newscategory').change(function () {
                        cleardrop();
                    $.post("/import-conditions/plants/listscommodity?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                          {
                              $( "select#newscommodity").html(data)

                          })                           

                        });     

                       $('#newscommodity').change(function () {

                         $.post("/import-conditions/plants/listsspecies?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                           {
                               $( "select#newsspecies").html(data)

                           })      

                            $.post("/import-conditions/plants/listsintendeduse?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                           {
                               $( "select#newsintendeduse").html(data)

                          }) 

                      $.post("/import-conditions/plants/listsorigin?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                           {
                               $( "select#newsorigin").html(data)

                           }) ; 
                           });      

                           $('#newsorigin').change(function () {
                            $.post("/import-conditions/plants/listsfinalitysinglesearch?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                                                                {
                                                                    $( "select#newsorigin").html(data)

                                                                });
                           });               


        }
        else if(impcat==''){

                                      $('#newscategorylabel').addClass("hide");                                  
                                       $('#newscommoditylabel').addClass("hide");                                    
                                         $('#newsgroupslabel').addClass("hide");                                        
                                           $('#newsoriginlabel').addClass("hide");                                           
                                             $('#newsmanufacturelabel').addClass("hide");
                                               $('#newsintendeduselabel').addClass("hide"); 
                                                $('#newsfinalitylabel').addClass("hide");
                                                 $('#newsspecieslabel').addClass("hide"); 

                                     cleardrop();

        }   

     });


    }
     else if(dept=='Food Safety')
    { 
        $("#newsimportcategory").html(
        ["<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>",
        "<option value='Process Food Products'>Process Food Products</option>"
        ]); 
             $('#newsimportcategory').change(function () {
             var impcat= $(this).val();             
           $.post("/import-conditions/admin/processfood/listsimptcat",function(data)
              {
                  $( "select#newscategory").html(data)


              });

        if(impcat=='Process Food Products'){

                                     $('#newscategorylabel').removeClass("hide");
                                     $('#newscommoditylabel').removeClass("hide");
                                      $('#newsmanufacturelabel').removeClass("hide");                                    
                                       $('#newsoriginlabel').removeClass("hide");
                                         $('#newsspecieslabel').addClass("hide");                                   
                                         $('#newsfinalitylabel').addClass("hide");                                       
                                           $('#newsgroupslabel').addClass("hide");
                                            $('#newsintendeduselabel').addClass("hide");


                                             $('#newscategory').change(function () {
                                                cleardrop();
                                                $.post("/import-conditions/processfood/listscommodity?name=" + $(this).val(),function(data)
                                                {
                                                    $('#newscommodity').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
                                                     $('#newsmanufacture').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
                                                      $('#newsorigin').html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");

                                                    $( "select#newscommodity").html(data); 

                                                });
                                            });

                                             $('#newscommodity').change(function () {

                                                 $.post("/import-conditions/processfood/listsmanufacture?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                                                                {
                                                                    $( "select#newsmanufacture").html(data)

                                                                });   
                                                            $.post("/import-conditions/processfood/listsorigin?name=" +$(this).val(),function(data)
                                                                {
                                                                    $( "select#newsorigin").html(data)

                                                                }); 

                                             });

        }
        else if(impcat==''){

                                      $('#newscategorylabel').addClass("hide");                                  
                                       $('#newscommoditylabel').addClass("hide");                                    
                                         $('#newsgroupslabel').addClass("hide");                                        
                                           $('#newsoriginlabel').addClass("hide");                                           
                                             $('#newsmanufacturelabel').addClass("hide");
                                               $('#newsintendeduselabel').addClass("hide"); 
                                                $('#newsfinalitylabel').addClass("hide");
                                                 $('#newsspecieslabel').addClass("hide"); 

                                     cleardrop();

        }      


    });

}

 });
```

_form.php

```
    <?php

            use yii\helpers\Html;
            use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
            use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

            /* @var $this yii\web\View */
            /* @var $model backend\models\News */
            /* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" ></script>
            <div class="news-form">

            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

            <div id="pagecontent">
                <h1 align="center">
                    Add New News Form
                </h1>
                <br />
 <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8">
                    <tr>
 <td width="30%" align="Right"><h2><strong>News Heading: </strong></h2></td>
 <td width="70%"><label>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'headline')->textInput(['style' => 'width: 900px'])->label(false) ?>
  </label></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td align="right"><h2><strong>Content: </strong></h2></td>
                        <td><label>
                             <?= $form->field($model, 'story')->textarea(['rows' => 6,'style' => 'width: 900px; height: 380px;'])->label(false) ?>


 </label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="30%" align="Right"><h2><strong>Department: </strong></h2></td>
<td width="70%"><label>
 <?= $form->field($model, 'department')->textInput(['style' => 'width: 400px','readonly'=>true,'value'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->department,'id'=>'newsdepartment'])->label(false) ?>
   </label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td width="30%" align="Right"><h2><strong>Import Category: </strong></h2></td>
 <td width="70%"><label>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'importcategory')->dropDownList(
                                                                    ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),
  [   
'id'=>'newsimportcategory',                                                             
'style' => 'width:400px',
  ])->label(false);?>
 </label></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td align="right"><h2><strong>Items: </strong></h2></td>
<td><label>
<div class="hide" id="newscategorylabel"><label class="control-label">Category: </label>
 <?= $form->field($model, 'category')->dropDownList(                                                                    ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),
['id'=>'newscategory', 
'style' => 'width:400px',
])->label(false);?>
  </div>                          
<div class="hide" id="newscommoditylabel"><label class="control-label">Commodity: </label>
<?= $form->field($model, 'commodity')->dropDownList(
                                                                    ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),
 [                                                                        'id'=>'newscommodity', 
'style' => 'width:400px',
 ])->label(false);?>                                   
           </div>
 <div class="hide" id="newsgroupslabel"><label class="control-label" >Groups: </label>                                                  
<?= $form->field($model, 'groups')->dropDownList(
                                                                    ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),             ['id'=>'newsgroups',                                                             
 'style' => 'width:400px',
 ])->label(false);?>
    </div>
     <div class="hide" id="newsspecieslabel"><label class="control-label" >Species: </label>                                 
<?= $form->field($model, 'species')->dropDownList(
                                                                    ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),            ['id'=>'newsspecies',         
'style' => 'width:400px',
 ])->label(false);?>                                   
          </div>                                 
<div class="hide" id="newsintendeduselabel"><label class="control-label" >Intended Use: </label>

<?= $form->field($model, 'intendeduse')->dropDownList(
                                                                    ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),
['id'=>'newsintendeduse',                                                             
'style' => 'width:400px',
])->label(false);?>                                   
           </div>                                  
<div class="hide" id="newsoriginlabel"><label class="control-label" >Country of Origin: </label>

<?= $form->field($model, 'origin')->dropDownList(
                                                                    ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),
 [
'id'=>'newsorigin',  
'style' => 'width:400px',
  ])->label(false);?>
   </div>
 <div class="hide" id="newsmanufacturelabel"><label class="control-label" >Manufacture: </label>                
<?= $form->field($model, 'manufacture')->dropDownList(
                                                                    ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),
 [      
'style' => 'width:400px',
])->label(false);?>                                 
 </div>
 <div class="hide" id="newsfinalitylabel"><label class="control-label" >Finality: </label>

<?= $form->field($model, 'finality')->dropDownList(
                                                                    ArrayHelper::map(['empty'=>'Empty string'], 'id', 'value'),
[ 'id'=>'newsfinality',                                                             
'style' => 'width:400px',
  ])->label(false);?>

 </div>
  </label></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><h2><strong>Status</strong></h2></td>
                    <td><?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList([ 'Active' => 'Active', 'Restricted' => 'Restricted','Prohibited' => 'Prohibited' ], ['prompt' => 'Select Status','style' => 'width: 400px'])->label(false) ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><h2><strong>News Picture</strong></h2></td>
                    <td><label>
                        <?=$form->field($model, 'img')->fileInput()->label(false);?>
                    </label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="center"><label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Add News' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                </div>
                    </label></td>
                </tr>


                </table>
                <br />
                <br />

            </div>   

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

            </div>
```

Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\News;
use backend\models\NewsSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;


class NewsController extends Controller
{       
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }


    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $searchModel = new NewsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single News model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new News model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
          $timezone = "America/Belize";
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

        $model = new News();
         $model->created_date= date('d-m-Y h:i:s a');
        $model->input_user= Yii::$app->user->identity->username;



        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }


    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }


    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = News::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Model.php

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;    
use Yii;    

class News extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $importcategory;
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'news';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['headline', 'story', 'status', 'department', 'input_user', 'created_date'], 'required'],
            [['headline', 'story','importcategory'], 'string'],
            [['img', 'name', 'category', 'commodity', 'manufacture', 'groups', 'species', 'intendeduse', 'origin', 'finality', 'status', 'department', 'input_user', 'created_date'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['department'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Loginusers::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['department' => 'department']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'headline' => 'Headline',
            'img' => 'Img',
            'story' => 'Story',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'category' => 'Category',
            'commodity' => 'Commodity',
            'manufacture' => 'Manufacture',
            'groups' => 'Groups',
            'species' => 'Species',
            'intendeduse' => 'Intendeduse',
            'origin' => 'Origin',
            'finality' => 'Finality',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'department' => 'Department',
            'input_user' => 'Input User',
            'created_date' => 'Created Date',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getDepartment0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Loginusers::className(), ['department' => 'department']);
    }
}
```

I know the code is messy just learning javascript and jquery. Any suggestion on how to proceed? or have a better way of doing this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what happens on update, f12 in chrome opens the debugger to see any js errors. Yii2 also has a debugger that shows you errors, this only works when the yii2 environment is configured as dev.

Comment: where is your controller action code and the respective models , please add them as it wont be possible to guess what is being saved where that you are trying to load

Comment: I have added the controller. The problem with update is that the hidden dropdowns doesn't show up in update. I have it hidden on inital load but i cannot get it to show in update. I apologize for the long wait.

Comment: So to clarify on an update you want certain fields to appear that are not in the create view? 
Are they always the same fields? or is it only if those fields have values?

Comment: Yes. The same fields that are shown in create i want it to be shown in update. The javascript hide the fields but i cannot find how to get the script to show in update.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a lot of console.log('I am in function x, doing y') type comments in each of your functions at key locations. Next hit F12 in chrome to see the console debugger and see if you are undoing some of your hide unhide multiple times.

**Example: JavaScript Console**

```
function makeIconFromHex() {
    console.log('makeIconFromHex..............');
    console.log(matrix);

    var width = matrix[0].length;
    var height = matrix.length;
}
```

Alternatviely, maybe something like this is better:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'somefield')
    ->textInput(['hidden'=> $model->isNewRecord ? false : true])
    ->label(false) ?>
```

Comment: Well it's the div that i am hiding. <div class="hide"></div> that hides the fields. Then in javascript i remove the class .removeClass("hide"). But because i hide the fields in the initial load then i am unable to show them in update. do note because i have an onchange that will make the fields show only when the value match the one i have in the javascript. i have 5 main category. Animal, Plant, Process food, beneficial and vetdrugs. but some category have similar fields and some doesn't

Comment: eg. if the category is animal health then it will show fields (category,species,origin,commodity,finality).
if category is vet drugs then it shows field (category,commodity,groups,origin,manufacture)
if category is plant and plant products then it shows (category,species,commodity,origin,intendeduse) etc

Comment: I see, let me post you a better solution tonight.

Comment: Ok sure. The only problem is to show the fields that was use in create in update.